# Sass $base_color change not working on Sencha Touch

Tags: css, sass, sencha-touch

I'm new to SaaS and Sencha Touch, but I am trying to change the base colour to a nice green. Here is the code from my rbTheme.scss file:

```
$base_color: #546346;

// The following two lines import the default Sencha Touch theme. If you are building
// a new theme, remove them and the add your own CSS on top of the base CSS (which
// is already included in your app.json file).
@import 'sencha-touch/default';
@import 'sencha-touch/default/all';
// Custom code goes here..



// Examples of using the icon mixin:
// @include icon('user');
```

I have changed the CSS path to rbTheme.css in app.json and I have also compiled with compass too, but it doesn't seem to have made a difference.

On closer inspection it looks like it is being inserted into the CSS, but it is still not displaying?

Comment: If the generated CSS appears to be correct, can you provide the relevant CSS + markup to reproduce the problem?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

According to [this blogpost](http://miamicoder.com/2013/creating-a-custom-theme-for-a-sencha-touch-application/), perhaps you might need an extra `!default` property on your `base_color` variable. Like this:

```
$base_color: #546346 !default;

// The following two lines import the default Sencha Touch theme. If you are building
// a new theme, remove them and the add your own CSS on top of the base CSS (which
// is already included in your app.json file).
@import 'sencha-touch/default';
@import 'sencha-touch/default/all';
// Custom code goes here..



// Examples of using the icon mixin:
// @include icon('user');
```

Comment: hmmm. ok. I googled a bit and will modify my answer with another suggestion :) Let's see if that helps.

Comment: you're welcome. Hmmm...kinda strange someone downvoted my answer though :|

Comment: The OP doesn't say that your solution solved the problem (because it won't, that's not what `!default` is for).  The OP says the blog post helped, which makes this a link-only answer.